# Read context param value in spring configuration xml

Tags: spring, tomcat

Added the following parameter in context.xml

```
<Parameter name="channel" value="any"
         override="false"/>
```

I want to read the value of channel in spring configuration xml

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="READ_VALUE_OF_CHANNEL_PARAMETER" />
```

READ_VALUE_OF_CHANNEL_PARAMETER needs to be replaced.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="#{contextParameters.channel}" />
```